# Python Matplotlib Bar Plot Y-axis Sticklabel

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to generate a set of bar plots using following code. As can be seen(if you run the code in jupyter notebook), figure 1 and figure 3 are working fine but figure 2 and figure 4 have problems. It seems that my settings for y-axis ticks label cannot overwrite the original labels, thus the figure is showing both. Can someone help me debug this? Thank you.

Result figure:
[image: Result of following code]

Code:

```
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.figure as fig
import numpy as np
import math

cr1=[4.19,3.71,2.78,2.19,2.17,3.05,5.23,9.86,19.44,39.35,74.86,160.09]
cr2=[340.94,349.54,343.75,345.88,390.87,298.74,343.07,310.83,265.43,97.25,126.49,90.03]
cr3=[1.51,1.51,1.51,1.51,1.51,2.48,5.01,9.80,20.43,45.92,90.24,464.10]
cr4=[1.54,1.64,1.76,1.90,1.99,1.72,1.29,1.29,1.29,2.31,4.57,8.56]

CR = np.array([cr1,cr2,cr3,cr4])
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['cm'],'size':30})
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=25)

fig, axes  = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True,figsize=(20,20))
ind = np.arange(12)

axes[0][0].bar(ind, CR[0], width=0.3,log=True)
axes[0][1].bar(ind, CR[1], width=0.3,log=True)
axes[1][0].bar(ind, CR[2], width=0.3,log=True) 
axes[1][1].bar(ind, CR[3], width=0.3,log=True)

plt.setp(axes, xticks=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 
     xticklabels=[r"\textbf{1e-11}",'','','','','',r"\textbf{1e-5}",'','','','',r"\textbf{1e-0}"])

axes[0][0].set_title(r"\textbf{astro}")
axes[0][0].set_yticks([10,100])
axes[0][0].set_yticklabels([r"\boldmath{$1\mathrm{e}{1}$}",r"\boldmath{$1\mathrm{e}{2}$}"])

axes[0][1].set_title(r"\textbf{blast2}")
axes[0][1].set_yticks([100,200,300,400]) 
axes[0][1].set_yticklabels([r"\boldmath{$1\mathrm{e}{2}$}",r"\boldmath{$2\mathrm{e}{2}$}",r"\boldmath{$3\mathrm{e}{2}$}",r"\boldmath{$4\mathrm{e}{2}$}"])

axes[1][0].set_title(r"\textbf{bump}") 
axes[1][0].set_yticks([10,100]) 
axes[1][0].set_yticklabels([r"\boldmath{$1\mathrm{e}{1}$}",r"\boldmath{$1\mathrm{e}{2}$}"])

axes[1][1].set_title(r"\textbf{dpot}")
axes[1][1].set_yticks([2,4,6]) 
axes[1][1].set_yticklabels([r"\boldmath{$2\mathrm{e}{0}$}",r"\boldmath{$4\mathrm{e}{0}$}",r"\boldmath{$6\mathrm{e}{0}$}"])

plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

BTW, I've used similar code for axe.plot and axe.hist and they all worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing happens due to the minor ticks and labels being displayed on the 2nd and 4th axes as the scale is not large enough to actually encompass the major ticks. The solution would be to simply turn off the minor ticks to the axes which are automatically labelling the minor ticks:

```
axes[0,1].minorticks_off()
axes[1,1].minorticks_off()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Great! It seems perfect! I appreciate it!

Comment: @Jon.W No problem. If an answer solved your problem then consider [voting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful one